# Convert java to scala code

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Converting java to scala code I face a strange Problem 
An example can be found here https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/895260a04d3673b9848b345edf388a2d
The error is

```
[error] src/main/scala/myOrg/CustomInputMapperWKT.scala:17: overriding method call in trait FlatMapFunction of type (x$1: String)java.util.Iterator[Any];
[error]  method call has incompatible type
[error]   override def call(line: String): Iterator[_] = {
```

When trying to convert spark java to spark scala API
I am struggling to port this java class https://github.com/DataSystemsLab/GeoSpark/blob/master/src/main/java/org/datasyslab/geospark/showcase/UserSuppliedPolygonMapper.java#L59-L81 to scala.

Where

```
class CustomInputMapperWKT extends FlatMapFunction[String, Any] {
....
override def call(line: String): Iterator[_] = {
val result: collection.Seq[Polygon] with Growable[Polygon] = mutable.Buffer[Polygon]()
result.iterator
  }
}
```

is the minimal sample describing the problem.

## edit

Trying to fix a possible typing problem I substituted Any with its respective type of polygon. 
But that doesn't help to Fox the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this signature?

```
override def call(t: String): java.util.Iterator[Any] = {
...
```

Because this code example is compiled successfully:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction
import collection.JavaConverters._

class CustomInputMapperWKT extends FlatMapFunction[String, Any] {
  override def call(t: String): java.util.Iterator[Any] = {
    ...
    result.iterator.asJava
  }
}
```

Comment: This is partly on the right track. the new Problem now is that `val result: collection.Seq[Polygon] with Growable[Polygon] = mutable.Buffer[Polygon]()` when called as `result.iterator` will not produce a java.util.iterator but rather `type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Iterator[com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon]
[error]  required: java.util.Iterator[com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon]
`

Comment: can you use `JavaConverters` as I did? 
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html

Comment: When using `val javaList: java.util.List[Polygon] = scala.collection.JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(result)
    javaList.iterator()` it will compile but that is not clean scala code. Do you see an alternative? Strangely the implicit mapper will not work.

Comment: if return of `result.iterator.asJava` doesn't work, it will be hard to say right now

Comment: looks like that. strange.